# Return statements

Tags: java, return

How do I get this code to work? I need to return the statements from the 3 scenarios, currently I'm getting an error at String robotInfo.

```
String generateStatusReport(Robot robot) {

    String robotStatus;
    String robotWall;
    String robotGround;
    String robotInfo = robotStatus + robotWall + robotGround;

    if(isRobotDead(robot)) {
        robotStatus = ("The robot is dead.");
    } else {
        robotStatus = ("The robot is alive.");
        if(isRobotFacingWall(robot)) {
            robotWall = ("The robot is facing a wall.");
        } else {
            robotWall = ("The robot is not facing a wall.");
        }

        if(isItemOnGroundAtRobot(robot)) {
            robotGround = ("There is an item here.");
        } else {
            robotGround = ("There is no item here.");
        }
    }
    return robotInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move your concatenation to after the conditional but before the return statement:

```
String generateStatusReport(Robot robot) {

    String robotStatus;
    String robotWall;
    String robotGround;

    if(isRobotDead(robot))
        robotStatus = ("The robot is dead.");
    else {
        robotStatus = ("The robot is alive.");
        if(isRobotFacingWall(robot))
            robotWall = ("The robot is facing a wall.");
        else
            robotWall = ("The robot is not facing a wall.");

        if(isItemOnGroundAtRobot(robot))
            robotGround = ("There is an item here.");
        else
            robotGround = ("There is no item here.");
    }
    String robotInfo = robotStatus + robotWall + robotGround;
    return robotInfo;
}
```

Or just return the concatenation:

```
return robotStatus + robotWall + robotGround;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your strings to get a value in robotInfo

```
String robotStatus;
    String robotWall;
    String robotGround;
```